# Why do IDL defaultvalue values look rounded?

Tags: vba, com, vb6, idl

I have a COM object with a function with an optional last argument. The IDL is a bit like this:

```
interface ICWhatever: IDispatch
{
  [id(96)] HRESULT SomeFunction([in,defaultvalue(50.6)]float parameter);
};
```

This works fine: if I don't specify the parameter, 50.6 is filled in.
But in several development environments (Excel VBA, VB6) the default value is rounded before display. After typing the open brace, I see:

> SomeFunction(**[*parameter As Single = 51*]**)

Does anyone know why this is? Is it a bug? This will confuse client programmers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem you experienced (VBA), and it appears to be indeed **a bug in the treatment of the `Single` type by (specifically) VB IDEs**.  Namely, the VB IDEs will improperly cast the `Single` default value to `int` before printing it out again (as part of the method signature) as a (truncated) single-precision floating-point value.

This problem does not exist in the *Microsoft Script Editor*, nor does it exist in `OleView.exe` etc.

To test, try the following `Single` default value: `18446744073709551615.0`.  In my case, this value is properly encoded in the TLB and properly displayed by `OleView.exe` and by *Microsoft Script Editor* as `1.844674E+19`.  However, it gets displayed as `-2.147484E+09` in the VB IDEs.  Indeed, casting `(float)18446744073709551615.0` to `int` produces `-2147483648` which, displayed as `float`, produces the observed (incorrect) VB IDE output `-2.147484E+09`.

Similarly, `50.6` gets cast to `int` to produce `51`, which is then printed out as `51`.

**To work around this issue use `Double` instead of `Single`**, as `Double` is converted and **displayed properly** by all IDEs I was able to test.

---

*On a tangent, you are probably already aware of the fact that certain floating point values (such as `0.1`) do not have a corresponding* exact *IEEE 754 representation and cannot be distinguished from other values (e.g. `0.1000000015`.)  Thus, specifying a default* double-precision *value of `0.1` will be displayed in most IDEs as `0.100000001490116`.  One way to alleviate this precision issue is to choose a different scale for your parameters (e.g. switch from seconds to milliseconds, thus `0.1` seconds would become `100` milliseconds, unambiguously representable as both single- and double precision floating point, as well as integral values/parameters.)*